# why ChainShape body is not falling on ground?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

[image]

The gravity is turned on. Other bodies like Polygonshape is behaving normally but my chainshape body just freezes to the position when it touches the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** Chain shapes aren't designed for full dynamics.

**Longer answer:** The [box2d.org manual](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf) explains that Chain shapes are for constructing your static worlds. In this regard, Chain shapes are similar to Edge shapes:

> they can collide with circles and polygons but not with themselves.

Furthermore, they're not designed for fully dynamic behaviors like shapes such as the Polygon shape.

Hope this answers your question.